# Parquet Datatype Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a bunch of parquet files and I've created external tables using Impala's `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE...`.

However when I issued

```
select * from my_table
```

it returned

> ERROR: File 'hdfs://xyz..' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 'xyz'. Column type: DECIMAL(5, 2), Parquet schema:optional int32 final_apr [i:4 d:1 r:0].

So I closely looked at the output of command

```
parquet-tools schema my_parquet
```

and observed that all the columns which are `INT64` but not `fixed_len_byte_array` having this issue.

So I manually executed the command

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table_name CHANGE old-column new_column BIGINT;
```

to change the column type whatever it created by default to `BIGINT` per https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_parquet.html, then I was able to execute the `select * from my_table;`

I've exercised the above in scala using spark, i.e I was able to read parquet file and store it as impala table and also can able to issue "select * from my_table" query programmatically.

However I tried to manually query from impala shell, I'm encountering the same error shown above.

Instead of manually updating the columns to change the datatype of all `INT64` non-fixed-length byte array, is there any better way to handle this? May be something like after reading parquet file as Dataframe, find out all `INT64` non-fixed-length byte array column convert them to `BIGINT` then save the dataframe as table?

BTW, I'm not able to execute `select * from my_from;` query in hive shell even after changing the column's data type. I'm getting errors msg

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:30 extraneous input 'limit' expecting Number near '' (state=42000,code=40000).

I tried with couple tables, all of them are having the same issue with hive shell.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Four distinct Apache projects -- Hive, Parquet, Impala, Spark -- means lots of version compatibility issues. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279870/why-cant-impala-read-parquet-files-after-spark-sqls-write

Comment: from impala shell perspective, this issue resolved in Impala 2.11.0   per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2494 . The current version we use is Impala Shell v2.7.0-cdh5.9.1 ; unfortunately we can't upgrade impala shell in near future. as mentioned, trying to find out a way to programmatically correct when we create a table instead changing the column type to BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet schema's warning int32 means that your impala column type should be int not bigint. When you alter table column to int, it should work.
Btw, spark and impala parquet read methods are different. Impala follows a more conservative way to read parquet files. For example; spark does not control the number of values in different column indices while the impala do.

Comment: I pasted INT32 error accidentally assuming INT64 related error. but I've the same issue for INT64 as well but I'm more concerned INT64 related error because we have many of these columns in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue copying parquet data from s3 to redshift with a decimal column.  I was getting

```
  code:      15001
  context:   File 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/filename.snappy.parquet  
             has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 
             's3://bucket/filename/.column_name'. Column type: DECIMAL(9
```

The column in redshift was a `DECIMAL(9,5)`.  The column in parquet was a `double`.  I couldn't change the database because production.  I ended up modifying the parquet output like so:

```
val nineFive =  DataTypes.createDecimalType(9,5)
val df2 = df.withColumn("column_name", $"column_name" cast nineFive)
```