# Athena/Hive timestamp in parquet files written by spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, parquet

We are writing files from spark and read from Athena/Hive. 
We had an issue with timestamp when using hive.

```
 scala> val someDF = Seq((8, "2018-06-06 11:42:43")).toDF("number", "word")
someDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int, word: string]

scala> someDF.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("delimiter", "\u0001").save("s3://test/")
```

This creates a parquet file and I created a table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test5`(
  `number` int, 
  `word` timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test/'
```

Select query Failed with issue:
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field word's type BINARY in parquet is incompatible with type timestamp defined in table schema

Same thing is working when testing with plain csv file.

```
scala>someDF.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite").option("delimiter", "\u0001").save("s3://test")

Table:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test7`(
  `number` int, 
  `word` timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test/'
```

Can you please help with what is going wrong when we write it as parquet file.

Comment: Can you state the spark version you use?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279870/why-cant-impala-read-parquet-files-after-spark-sqls-write

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter is the only right answer. This is still happening in 2020. I would hope that this is way more visible as the way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a well known bug with Hive storing parquet timestamps [in a way that is incompatible with other tools](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12767). I have faced a similar problem while using Impala to retrieve Hive data that I have written with Spark. I believe [this was resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12297) in Spark 2.3.