# parquet fields showing NULL when reading through HIVE, BUT showing values when reading through spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am writing my spark streaming data frame as parquet file in my HDFS. I have created hive table in top of that HDFS location.
my spark structured streaming write command as follows:

```
   parquet_frame.writeStream.option("compression", "none").option("latestFirst", "true").option("startingOffsets", "latest").option("checkpointLocation", "/user/ddd/openareacheckpoint_feb/").outputMode("append").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).partitionBy("dfo_data_dt").format("parquet").option("path", "hdfs://ddd/apps/hive/warehouse/ddddd.db/frg_drag/").start().awaitTermination()
```

if i try to read data from HIVE, am getting NULL for double data types,INT data types except for string and BIGINT.

BUT the same HDFS file i have read through spark shell and it is getting generated values without any NULL.
command in spark to read parquet file:

```
val pp = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://ddd/apps/hive/warehouse/ddddd.db/frg_drag/dfo_data_dt=20190225/")
   pp.show
```

my create table statement in HIVE as follows:

```
        CREATE TABLE `ddddd.frg_drag`(
     `unit` string,
     `pol` string,
     `lop` string,
     `gok` string,
     `dfo_call_group` string,
     `dfo_dfr` double,
     `dfo_dfrs` double,
     `dfo_dfrf` double,
     `dfo_dfra` double,
     `dfo_dfrgg` double,
     `dfo_dfrqq` double,
     `dfo_w_percent` double,
     `dfo_afv_percent` double,
     `dfo_endfd` double,
     `dfo_time` timestamp,
     `dfo_data_hour` int,
     `dfo_data_minute` int)
   PARTITIONED BY (
     `dfo_data_dt` bigint)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
   STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
   OUTPUTFORMAT
     'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
   LOCATION
     'hdfs://ddd/apps/hive/warehouse/ddddd.db/frg_drag'
   TBLPROPERTIES (
      'transient_lastDdlTime'='1551108381')
```

can some help me how can resolve this issue. I am new to spark world

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Impala read parquet files after Spark SQL's write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279870/why-cant-impala-read-parquet-files-after-spark-sqls-write)

Comment: do we have any resolution ? i couldn't find the link shared

Comment: I have tried with ("spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat", "true") , but its not working still reflecting  NULL